# React table cell unmounts?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

When using react table we usually I'm often thrown off by the constant un- und mounting of the cell components. Here is an example ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-hodgkin-yp4xgh?file=/src/App.js:0-2666)):

```
const data = [{ name: "Lukas" }];

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const columns = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      {
        Header: "name",
        accesspor: "name",
        Cell: (props) => {
          useEffect(() => () => console.log("unmount"), []);
          return (
            <div>
              {props.value} + {count}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
    ];
  }, [count]);

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({ data, columns });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>increment</button>
      <div>
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
            ...render the table
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `column` array depends on `count`. If we increment count, all cells are fully unmounted. I've tried adding `key` props to signal a stable entity - but found no way to prevent unmounting.

**Why I this unmounting problematic?** In case nested components reliy on state, the state is fully reset on unmount.

Is there any way to prevent `Cell` components from being unmounted?

Comment: Do you have a version with your attempt at adding `key`s? I would have expected that to be the solution here.

Comment: sure: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-5h5cvb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think the reason, the `key` may not work has to do with `Cell` being an anonoymous function component. But thats just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is caused by `columns` being redefined every time `count` changes and the `useMemo` callback executes. As a result, the anonymous function for `Cell` is redefined and this causes a mount and unmount. You can check this by removing `count` from the deps of the `useMemo`.

To solve this you need to find a way of making `columns` not depend on `count`. Perhaps you can find a way to pass the count to the React table context directly. One way is using `meta`. See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-breeze-j4whr4?file=/src/App.js).